# Submultiplicativity of $f(A)=\max_{i=1,...,n}i\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the matrix norm $$f(A)=\max_{i=1,...,n}i\cdot\sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$$ for matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ submultiplicative?

---

I haven't been able to prove that it is but I also haven't been able to give a counterexample so far since every pair of matrices I try out doesn't seem to work and would very much appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(A)$ simply equals $\|DA\|_\infty$, where $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)$. Since the induced $\infty$-norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ (i.e. the absolute row sum norm) is submultiplicative,
$$
f(AB)=\|DAB\|_\infty\le\|DA\|_\infty\|B\|_\infty\le\|DA\|_\infty\|DB\|_\infty=f(A)f(B).
$$